# Accessing json data in ext js4?

Tags: php, json, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am developing web site in Ext Js4 with yii framework.I am getting stuck on a point which is how to access json data returned from server into Ext js 4.Actually I want to display the message field as well as every fields in json code in ext js 4. how can I do that?

**Here is my json code (server response in the form of json)**

```
{

    "success": true,
    "data": [
        { 
            "msg": "uname and pass wrong"
        }
    ]

}
```

**Here is my model class code**

```
Ext.define('AM.model.Login',
        {
            extend:'Ext.data.Model',
            idProperty:'id',
            fields:['id','uname','pass'],
            proxy:
            {
                type:'ajax',
                url:'http://localhost/Balaee3/index.php?r=site/contact',

                reader:
                    {
                        type:'json',
                        root:'data',
                        successProperty:'success'
                    },//end of reader
                writer:
                    {
                        type:'json',
                        root:'records',
                        //writeAllFields:true
                    },//End of writer

            }//end of proxy
        }
);
```

**How can I access json code in controller file in ext js4**
here i want to display my json data.

```
            AM.model.Login.load(512, {
            params: {
            id: 512 
            },
            success: function(record, operation) {
            character = record; 
            },//end of success
            failure: function(record, operation) 
            {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Failed to load model from the server.');
            },//end of failure
            callback: function(record, operation) {
                //Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Model loaded successfully.');
                console.log('Success', 'Model loaded successfully.');
                            }//end of call back function
            });
```

give me some suggestions

Comment: Do you only need this for a specific load operation, or globally (so the mechanism is the same every time you load a model)?

Comment: And do you get the correct response by `console.log(operation.response.responseText);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a  messageProperty in your model.
try something like this....

```
reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',          
        successProperty : 'success',
        messageProperty : 'message',
        implicitIncludes: true
    }
```

### controller(server)

```
 def message=''    
    def json = request.JSON       
    message=data.message
    def metaData = [ successProperty : 'success', messageProperty : 'message', totalProperty:'num', root:'data']
    def jsonData = [metaData:metaData, success:flag, message:message]
    render jsonData as JSON
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But still not getting any field. I also added some code console.log('success',operation.response.scope.reader.jsonData['msg']);  but it displays  success undefined